# How to perform action when Shift+Enter is pressed?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a TextBox in a C#/XAML desktop app and I want to detect the <kbd>Shift+Enter</kbd> command. How can I do this?

So far I have only been able to find information on commands like Ctrl+A, etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @BlackICE yep, I've read that. It's a good read, isn't it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Enter))
{
    MessageBox.Show("test");
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Shoe! This works great when `AcceptsReturn` is set to `false` on the TextBox. Any idea how to get it to work when `AcceptsReturn` is set to `true`?

Comment: My bad, I typed it into the wrong event. It's working great now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`ModifierKeys.Shift` allows you to identify key pressed combinations which includes *Shift*:

```
private void HandleKeyDownEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Key == Key.Enter && (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift))
   {
      // Handle..
   }
}
```

Another option is [`Keyboard.IsKeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.iskeydown%28VS.85%29.aspx) static method *(see Shoe's answer)*.

Comment: If shift+enter is pressed this will pass, but if a third key is pressed (like shift+enter+d) it will fail.

Comment: @Shoe But this is exactly how key combination commands should work, no?!

Comment: Depends on how much flexibility is needed, really.

Answer (score 0):

A good example can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yazd4ct6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
public void TextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Pressed " + Keys.Shift);
    }
}
```